# Clearing/Emptying the previous TD value when a new option value is selected in the select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I really need your help, how can the existing code be modified below such that upon selecting another option value from the select box, the previous `<td>` text value in the table should be cleared.

Here is an pic of the problem:

[image]

Here is the HTML Markup and code in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

$(document).on('click', '.ufield', function() {

  if($(this).find('select').length == 0) {
      $(this).append("<select><option value=''></option><option value='ADMIN'>ADMIN</option><option value='USER'>USER</option></select>");
  }
});


$(document).on('change', '.ufield select', function(){
    var myValue = $(this).val();
    var $parent = $(this).parent();

    $(this).remove();
    $parent.append(myValue);
});













}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td>User ID:</td>
        <td>JSMITH</td>
        <td>Branch:</td>
        <td>TESTA</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Access:</td>
        <td class="ufield" id="access"></td>
        <td>Floor:</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Account Status:</td>
        <td>active</td>
        <td>Office:</td>
        <td>D5656</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Last Login:</td>
        <td>30/08/2016 4:16 PM</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Firstname:</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Address:</td>
        <td>175 Yahoo Lane</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lastname:</td>
        <td>Smith</td>
        <td>Province:</td>
        <td>Ontario</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telephone:</td>
        <td>123-456-7891</td>
        <td>City:</td>
        <td>Niagra Falls</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Fax:</td>
        <td>613-990-1301</td>
        <td>Country:</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>E-mail:</td>
        <td>john_smith@yahoo.ca</td>
        <td>Postal Code:</td>
        <td>90210</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to add the value in front of the option? As far as i know every browser shows the currently selected value...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).remove();  ------>  $(this).closest("td").prev().empty();
```

Comment: Thats not an answer

Comment: maybe add more details on what exactly need to be done or attach a pic of the output you want. This is how you clear the text in the previous td tag "access:"

Comment: I know this. But the OP may not. So please provide a good answer wich explains your code...

Comment: hahah I see the OP just answered his own question by getting my point in my answer and used .empty() instead of .remove()

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick, modify the following section:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ufield', function() {

    if ($(this).html()) {
        $(this).empty()
    }

    $(this).append("<select><option value=''></option><option value='ADMIN'>ADMIN</option><option value='USER'>USER</option></select>");

    //if($(this).find('select').length == 0) {}

});
```

Comment: You really answered your own question??